# What happened to gsview 9.27 when ps2pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Could you help me look into below: 
we encountered ps2pdf conversion issue when we started to use gsview ghost script 9.27, before that it works all fine. We tried to convert .ps file to .pdf file but it hit error as this:

### -----------------------------------

-****Error: invalid token after startxcref. output maybe incorrect.

****Error: An error occured while reading XREF table.

****The file has been damaged. This may have been caused

****by a problem while converting or transferring the file.

****Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data.

****However, the output maybe incorr
..

.---------------------------------------------------------------

Does it happen just because of gsview version or there's anything wrong with the setup? We did not change configurations just upgrate the software only.

Please help. Thanks!!

---

Hi!
I added some more info for your review:

This is our command:
/usr/sfw/bin/ps2pdf/testing/final.ps /testing/final.pdf

When we opened the final.pdf in text the xref and startxref is empty still 
%ld

```
    <</Producer(GPL Ghostscript 9.27)
    /CreationDate(D:20200116161655+08'00')
    /ModDate(D:20200116161655+08'00')>>endobj
    xref
    0 %ld
    0000000000 65535 f 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
    %ld 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 22 /Root 1 0 R /Info 2 0 R
/ID [<91C5EFACD76E9956C2349FE99F02E3FA><91C5EFACD76E9956C2349FE99F02E3FA>]
>>
startxref
%ld
%%EOF
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the code that uses Ghostscript

Comment: Are you running on a recent Solaris version, by any chance? There was an issue identified in 9.50, and solved in the current (but not released code), that caused a similar symptom: http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff;h=b46142c94bde32f620bda18e3bc5912fbf999446;hp=a4c78f01d9a1bd9862b575f33aa48afddd167005

Comment: Hi @chrisl! Thanks for the reply. I'm running on Oracle Solaris 11.4 SPARC. any idea how do we fix it? thank you!

Comment: sher: you'll have to either get the patch from the link above and rebulid gs, or wait for the next release (around March). If you're using a gs package, report it to the maintainer (include the link above), they can pull the patch, and provide an update.